# How to reinitialize current page with angular pagination?

Tags: angular, pagination

I implemented pagination in angular application from this site: [pagination](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/pagination.html)

I have two components for search functionality. First is parent. It contains search parameters and button that calls method *onSearch()*. Second is child component with search results showed in list with pagination. This is how paging works in child component:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of searchResults | paginate: { itemsPerPage: numberOfItemsPerPage, currentPage: p, id: 'searchResults' };
             index as i; let even=even; let odd=odd">
<td class="gridItemLeft">
                    <span class="label leftAlign">{{ i + 1 + (p-1)*numberOfItemsPerPage }}</span>
                </td>
                <td class="gridItemLeft">
                    <span class="label leftAlign">{{ item.id }}</span>
                </td>
                <td class="gridItemLeft">
                    <a [routerLink]="[getRouterLinkPage(item.requestType), item.id]">{{ item.typeName }}</a>
                </td>
                <td class="gridItemLeft">
                    <span class="label leftAlign">{{ item.date | date:'medium' }}</span>
                </td>
                <td class="gridItemLeft">
                    <span class="label leftAlign">{{ item.applicationUserUsername }}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
...
<app-pagination-control (pageChange)="p = $event" autoHide="true" id="searchResults"></app-pagination-control>
```

I created this class:

```
 import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { DEFAULT_TEMPLATE, DEFAULT_STYLES } from './template';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

function coerceToBoolean(input: string | boolean): boolean {
    return !!input && input !== 'false';
}

/**
 * The default pagination controls component. Actually just a default implementation of a custom template.
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'app-pagination-control',
    template: DEFAULT_TEMPLATE,
    styles: [DEFAULT_STYLES],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class PaginationControlComponent {

    @Input() id: string;
    @Input() maxSize = 7;
    @Input()
    get directionLinks(): boolean {
        return this._directionLinks;
    }
    set directionLinks(value: boolean) {
        this._directionLinks = coerceToBoolean(value);
    }
    @Input()
    get autoHide(): boolean {
        return this._autoHide;
    }
    set autoHide(value: boolean) {
        this._autoHide = coerceToBoolean(value);
    }
    @Input()
    get responsive(): boolean {
        return this._responsive;
    }
    set responsive(value: boolean) {
        this._responsive = coerceToBoolean(value);
    }
    @Input() previousLabel = this.translateService.instant('Pagination.Previous');
    @Input() nextLabel = this.translateService.instant('Pagination.Next');
    @Input() screenReaderPaginationLabel = this.translateService.instant('Pagination.Pagination');
    @Input() screenReaderPageLabel = this.translateService.instant('Pagination.Page');
    @Input() screenReaderCurrentLabel = this.translateService.instant('Pagination.Current');
    @Output() pageChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

    constructor(
        private translateService: TranslateService
    ) {

    }

    private _directionLinks = true;
    private _autoHide = false;
    private _responsive = false;
}
```

p is set to 1 in child component.
There is a bug when I navigate to i.e. third page. Then press search button again. I should be on first page if new search returned more than one page in result set, but it stays on third page. **p** did not reinitialize. My question is how should I pass data to set currentPage to 1 when search event happen?

I tried to set p as Input element, set it in onSearch method to 1, and send it to child like this:

```
<child-component [p]='p'></child-component>
```

Comment: You should pass value of p from base component as an input on search click.

Comment: Why don't you reinitialize value of `p` in `onSearch()` function?

Comment: I tried but it did not work.

Comment: @Vanessa what you have tried? Input value or reintializing.

Comment: I edited code to show you.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by passing whole paginate object as input and setting currentPage property to 1 on search.